# How to access "change" account from LTC transaction?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, litecoin

I bought LTC on Coinbase, and then transferred it all to my Jaxx wallet address.

The transaction hjas been confirmed, and the amount sent shows in Jaxx. Looking at the transaction on blockcypher.com, there are 2 output addresses - my jaxx wallet and an unknown.

My searching suggested that the unknown was where the change went - as the allocated fee was higher than the actual fee paid. However, I have no idea how to access this change, from this other address. I assumed it would maybe return to Coinbase, however Coinbase still shows 0 as my LTC balance, and Jaxx balance shows only the amount sent to the primary output address.

How do I access this change?

Comment: If you can link a tx ID or receiving address so that someone can look up the tx, it will be easier to help you. Was the amount you received in your jaxx wallet less than expected?

Comment: Tx: https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/tx/8b76a36d30971c56c9f0a710a29eacc53a4a2cda9d204117d9a2c26f9af52534/

input was my coinbase, and the larger output was my jaxx. What is that other output, and how would I access it, assuming I am meant to be able to? Jax only recieved the larger amount of the 2.

Comment: You didn't answer the more important part of the question: did you receive less than expected? If the answer is no, then it is simple: that output is coinbase's change address, and thus not your litecoin.

Comment: I recieved the amount I expected when setting up the TX, but after reading online that the second output was the "change" to the transaction I should have access to, then yes I recieved less than expected.

Comment: The change address belongs to the sender of the transaction, not the receiver. In this case, Coinbase sent the LTC to your receiving address. So the LTC in the sent to the address  LcBnfq... belong to coinbase, not you.